# tricky associate array insertion in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, associative-array, query-builder

My table looks like this

```
+---------+-------------+----------+
|  day    | start_time  | end_time |
+---------+-------------+----------+
|  monday | 10:00:00    | 12:00:00 |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

The associate array i am getting from form is looking like this

```
  [timeslot] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 1
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1:15 PM
                            [1] => 4:15 PM
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2:15 PM
                            [1] => 5:15 PM
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 2
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 3
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 4
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 5
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 6
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [weekday] => 7
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1:15 PM
                        )

                    [to] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3:15 PM
                        )

                )

        )
```

normal array insert in Codeigniter doesn't work for this. any work around for this.

I need to store this like

```
+---------+-------------+----------+
|  day    | start_time  | end_time |
+---------+-------------+----------+
|  monday | 12:30:00    | 01:30:00 |
|  monday | 04:30:00    | 06:30:00 |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

I tried to insert it using

```
$this->db->insert('time_slots', $data);
```

but this is failing of the associate format i have.

I also thought to loop through **my array if from and to are arrays**

and insert the data using the above command but i doubt a performance issue.

Comment: post you code, what you try?

Comment: what is from and to value ? how you are passing data to model ?

Comment: from and to are the values i am getting from a input tag in a form,  i am struck at passing data to model :)

Comment: it from (start_time) and to (end_time ) value is array with multiple value always ?

Comment: yes it will be an array always but i can't say with multiple values always but at least it will contain one value

Comment: how you are giving value to form in from and to ?
"from"=>["12.30PM","4.30PM"],
    "to"=>["1.30PM","6.30PM"]
make input name from[],and to[]
and let me know what ouput you get

Comment: the name attribute is like this name="timeslot[1][to][]", where 1 represents weekday i.e monday and it is same to from name="timeslot[1][from][]"

Comment: then its
array(
    "day"=>"monday",
    "from"=>["12.30PM","4.30PM"],
    "to"=>["1.30PM","6.30PM"]
)
not your post value. what is value of $_POST ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84547/discussion-between-user1048123-and-saikiran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make array like this and pass to model

```
  $weekDay = array('1'=>'Sunday','2'=>'Monday','3'=>'Tuesday','4'=>'Wednesday','5'=>'Thurday','6'=>'Friday','7'=>'Saturday');
    foreach($_POST['timeslot'] as $key=>$val){
        foreach($val['from'] as $k=>$v){
            $day = $val['weekday'];
            $data[] = array(
                    'day'=>$weekDay[$day],
                    'start_time'=>$v['from'],
                    'end_time'=>$val['to'][$k]
            );
        }
    }


$this->db->insert_batch('time_slots', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working like this

```
        foreach ($_POST['timeslot'] as $key => $val) {

                switch($val['weekday']){
                    case 1:
                    $val['day']='monday';
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    $val['day']='tuesday';
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    $val['day']='wednesday';
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    $val['day']='thursday';
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    $val['day']='friday';
                    break;
                    case 6:
                    $val['day']='saturday';
                    break;
                    case 7:
                    $val['day']='sunday';
                    break;
                }
            if(count(array_filter($val['from']))>0){

                foreach($val['from'] as $k=>$v){
                    $tmp= array(
                            'day'=>$val['day'],
                            'start_time'=>$v,
                            'end_time'=>$val['to'][$k]
                    );

                    array_push($slots,$tmp);
                }
            }

        }
```

Count on `$val['from']` like this `count(array_filter($val['from']))` removes null and empty arrays.